# How do I get image handles and click&drag things around in Blender Compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm not new to Blender but I was wondering how to use the Blender Compositor the After Effects away or like any other compositing or video editing software, meaning I'd like to click onto an image or layer and move it around. It's slow and complicated to move things around with the trasform node parameters, especially if I want to do it precisely

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the 3d view?
import videos into emission shader planes and animate them.
I know it's stupid but I think it's the only way you can work graphically.

I wish that in 2.9 the Video editor thing will become Good!

Comment: I thought of that but it's not the best solution for me. By 2.9 do you mean Blender 2.9 or 2.81?

Comment: I didn't get what you meant @Yossi2010